# WPF ComboBox Background to match ComboBoxItem Background

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to bind the Background of a WPF ComboBox to the selected item's background in this Box. I found different solutions online but they seem to be very complicated with tons of lines of code.

Isn't there a simple way to do this? I found something like this:

```
<ComboBox Width="50" Height="50" Background="{Binding SelectedItem.Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
      <ComboBoxItem Background="#FFFF00" Height="50">bla</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any simple solution to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Nope.  WPF unfortunately gets complicated really quickly if you want any interesting things to happen :)